For which specific use-case is the new `System.Threading.Lock` in .Net 9 introduced?
I'm trying to wrap my head around the new System.Threading.Lock object in c#9.
In the old days I used to use good old lock(object) to prevent multiple threads accessing the same part of code like so:
public class LazyLoadedItem
{
}

private LazyLoadedItem _item = null;

private readonly object MyLock = new object();
   
public LazyLoadedItem GetItem
{
    get
    {
        {
            if (_item != null)
                return _item;

            lock (MyLock)
            {
                // Serve the queue of threads that passed the first check when the floodgates opened...
                if (_item != null)
                    return _item;

                _item = new LazyLoadedItem(); // get from Database/FileSystem/Web
            }

            return _item;
        }
    }
}

public void ClearCache()
{
    _item = null;
}

This worked well, and I could even safely do recursive stuff in the same thread using this lock since the lock was "thread-bound".
However.. since the await async era it was no longer safe to lock this way, since the thread would be reused as soon as it would need to wait for the database/web/filesystem or anything else. Since then I would adopt a new pattern using a SemaphoorSlim to ensure safe locking, like so:
private readonly SemaphoreSlim MyLock = new SemaphoreSlim(1, 1);

public async Task<LazyLoadedItem> GetItem(CancellationToken requestCancelled)
{
    if (_item != null)
        return _item;

    await MyLock.WaitAsync(requestCancelled); // throws exception when cancelled
    try
    {
        // Serve the queue of threads that passed the first check when the floodgates opened...
        if (_item != null)
            return _item;

        _item = await GetLazyLoadedItem().ConfigureAwait(false); // get from Database/FileSystem/Web
        // note that we may be continuing on a different thread here!
    }
    finally
    {
        MyLock.Release();
    }

    return _item;
}

Slightly off topic, but is it safe to await MyLock.WaitAsync(requestCancelled).ConfigureAwait(false);? I never dared to  ConfigureAwait(false) for this particular call.
Any way, my question about the new System.Threading.Lock is where does it fit in? Is it "async safe"?
If not I guess it's use is restricted to code that never awaits anything (for example caching calculations like total quantity * weight of some collection) which in my opinion reduces it's use-case to such a small margin that the introduction in c#9 is hardly justified. The only potential application I can come up with is caching reflection like so:
private static Dictionary<string, PropertyInfo> _props = null;

private static readonly System.Threading.Lock _myLock = new System.Threading.Lock();

public Dictionary<string,PropertyInfo> Props
{
    get
    {
        if (_props != null)
            return _props;

        lock (_myLock)
        {
            // Serve the queue of threads that passed the first check when the floodgates opened...
            if (_props != null)
                return _props;

            _props = this.GetType().GetProperties().ToDictionary(p => p.Name);
        }

        return _props;
    }
}

This may be useful for Serialization or Injection containers (as long as GetProperties() and ToDictionary() are not async), but since the lock would only be used for a fraction of the process lifetime during startup or at first-use the whole point of optimization is lost.
So why was the new System.Threading.Lock introduced? I guess in general the vast majority of code should stick to SemaphoreSlim? What am I missing?

Motivation is here.  The lock keyword uses the object header to keep track of lock state.  That gets awkward when the code also calls GetHashCode(), there's not enough room in the object header to track both.  Given that it makes little sense to do so, keeping lock objects stored in a hashmap or dictionary is arguable a questionable practice, there is no compelling reason I see to favor the Lock class.  But if you do then you've now got an alternative.

@HansPassant it's part performance and part syntax cleanup. The .NET team has said in the past that if using was available in 2002, there wouldn't be an explicit lock keyword. The benefits may look small as an average but multiply by 1M times/sec by number of cores and number of servers, they add up. The original proposal comes from Ben Adams, who works on MMOs

There are two main reasons for introduction of the new Lock type as far as I can see:

Clear declaration of intent - using dedicated type can make code cleaner and self-documenting.

There is a relatively small performance gain (but it can accumulate!) in some scenarios when using the new type (also check out my emphasis):

But locking a Lock can be a more efficient answer ...
As is evident from this benchmark, the syntax for using both can be identical.
// dotnet run -c Release -f net9.0 --filter "*"  
  
using BenchmarkDotNet.Attributes;  
using BenchmarkDotNet.Running;  
  
BenchmarkSwitcher.FromAssembly(typeof(Tests).Assembly).Run(args);  
  
[HideColumns("Job", "Error", "StdDev", "Median", "RatioSD")]  
public class Tests  
{  
    private readonly object _monitor = new();  
    private readonly Lock _lock = new();  
    private int _value;  
  
    [Benchmark]  
    public void WithMonitor()  
    {  
        lock (_monitor)  
        {  
            _value++;  
        }  
    }  
  
    [Benchmark]  
    public void WithLock()  
    {  
        lock (_lock)  
        {  
            _value++;  
        }  
    }  
}  

Lock, however, will generally be a tad cheaper (and in the future, as most locking shifts to use the new type, we may be able to make most objects lighter weight by not optimizing for direct locking on arbitrary objects):



Method
Mean




WithMonitor
14.30 ns


WithLock
13.86 ns







Is it "async safe"?

No. As the docs state:

When the lock is being entered and exited in a C# async method, ensure that there is no await between the enter and exit. Locks are held by threads and the code following an await might run on a different thread.

See also:

Add first class System.Threading.Lock type issue @github


The gain may look small until you realize locks often are in the hot path and those 44ms gained could be multiplied by 1M times per core.

I was hoping that I somehow was missing something big, but it looks like just a performance improvement for the existing lock. We don't have many of those in our code base. I guess the framework itself may benefit the most from this change. Having it as 2nd bullet point on the whats new in C#13 list is a little hyped. Marketing got me exited for 44ms in rare cases... well done.
